# Android dev: screen orientation

Tags: android

is it possible to change the layout of the app when the orientation of the screen changes from portrait to landscape ?
I mean linking the app to two different .xml layout files for each landscape and portrait?
or maybe is it possible to change placement of 2 views ?
like...
i want a button to be below the textview in portrait mode but i want them side by side in landscape mode...
:/
please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's one of the basic layout tips, might want to read through the tutorials on developer.android.com.

For this instance, just put the separate layout in res/layout-land (you'll have to make a new folder) with the same name as the portrait layout.

Comment: can you please give me the link ? 
i can find it :/

Comment: Well now I just feel bad; I can't find it on the dev site either now. However, Chris's answer above should help, and also this tutorial may help:

http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2009/12/android-layouts-supporting-orientation/

Answer (score 1):

Yes its actually very easy. In your `res` folder you have a `layout` folder with you layouts. Make a `layout-land` folder for your landscape layouts. The .xml files should have the same name as their counter parts in the `layout` folder. Android will automatically pick the right one at runtime during `onCreate` in your activities.

`/res/layout` - default if none exist for a particular condition
`/res/layout-land` - landscape layouts.

Note, you do not need to create duplicates if nothing is different for a particular layout, it will just use the default.